# How do I detect the bottlneck code line based on CPU usage?

Tags: python, profiling

I have a bottleneck code line in my python program that utilizes every CPU thread at 100%. Now, I'm seeking to pinpoint which process is causing this bottleneck.

I attempted to leverage the Python profiling tool `pyinstrument`, and here's an example of it.

[image]

However, the number on the left represents processing time, not CPU usage. Is there a method to write a summary of CPU usage for each code or Python function like this?

Comment: Have you tried the standard *profile* and/or *cProfile* modules? https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html